# Padded struct memory usage

Tags: c, struct, padding

I have a struct with 9 bytes worth of members. The sizeof() of the struct is returned as 10. I assume the extra byte is due to padding.
Will the padded byte ever be allowed to be used for anything, or does the compiler "reserve" it? i.e. is that memory forever lost as far as the program is concerned?

The reason for asking is I am very short of space so I have used one of the members for storage of several values in one byte using bit manipulation. However, if the padded byte is never otherwise used I can reduce complexity of accessing at least one of the values in the bit manipulated byte by having an extra byte value in place of the padded byte without increasing the overall size of the struct. 
But if possible I would rather reclaim the padded space to use for other variables. Ta.

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node * sibling, *child; // 2 * 2 bytes
    char * name; // 2 bytes
    handle callback; // 2 bytes
    uint16_t properties; // 1 byte
} node; // total by members = 9 bytes

totalSizeOfnode = sizeof(node); //totalSizeOfNode = 10
```

Comment: You can just add a `char` field at the end of your structure, and store whatever you want in it. It won't change `sizeof` nor the memory requirement. But your fields length is really weird. `sizeof uint_16t should == 2`, and, depending on the platform, `sizeof void* should == 4 or 8`

Comment: Why do you think uint16_t has size 1 byte?

Comment: It does on the uC I am currently using :)

Comment: `uint16_t properties; // 1 byte` Why is `uint16_t` = `1` byte? I mean according to its alias it should be a `typedef` of 16 bit data type.

Comment: @Toby : Oh!! the weird optimization...

Comment: Toby: Are you really sure that uint16_t is 1 byte on your compiler?  I thought I'd seen every perverse thing embedded toolchains could do, but that one stretches my credulity.  Which compiler is it?  It's not unknown for int to be one byte, but defining a fixed-length type to be the wrong length is just a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Am on TI 32-bit C2000, using TI C/C++ compiler in Code Composer Studio. By ANSI/ISO C sizeof(char) = 1, since on this uC a char is 16 bits (to make it separately addressable), 1 byte is 16 bits

Comment: `sizeof(char)` will *always* be one, no matter the actual bit-size of `char`. It's in the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, it won't be used. The members of a struct are generally aligned to best suit the underlying architecture it is running on.

On the other hand, most compilers will have to option to control this packing, so if you are short of memory you can tell the compiler to pack the struct members on a byte boundary. Note that this can potentially reduce performance because the CPU may need to do multiple reads to get members that are crossing word boundaries.

Comment: I have used `#pragma pack(1)` in my embedded programs.

Comment: :( that pragma's not available for my platform

Comment: What platform is that? I'd be surprised if there was no compiler option to do this.

Comment: Am on TI 32-bit C2000, using TI C/C++ compiler in Code Composer Studio IDE. Documentation actually mentions that it is not available for this platform.

Answer (score 1):

The padding space is always going to be available in the future, if you change the structure so that the padding is no longer required or is now occupied by a suitably-sized member.

If you think about the way a compiler works, there is no way that this space could be 'lost forever', because the compiler has no memory of how the source code used to be - it only knows how it is now.

Comment: Ah, in my 'lost forever' I meant for the life of the program. i.e. when the program is running and the byte is padded will other variables, from outside of the struct, be placed within these 'spare' bytes?

Comment: Ah, right - no it won't be reused - because it would be destroyed if you did something like a memset to the padded struct.